# Add index column which is under a hierarchical index PANDAS/python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want set the col1 as Index. The dataframe is the result of a concatenation and I using keys for created hierarchical index

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'col2': pd.Series([2, 3], index=[2, 3])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

d2 = {'col1': [0, 1, 4, 3], 'col2': pd.Series([4, 3], index=[2, 3])}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2, index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

result = pd.concat([df,df2], axis=1, keys=['PartieA', 'PARTIEB'])
print(result)
result.set_index(['col1'], append=True)
print(result)
```

I got this error:

```
KeyError: "None of ['col1'] are in the columns"
```

I have this:

```
PartieA      PARTIEB     
     col1 col2    col1 col2
0       0  NaN       0  NaN
1       1  NaN       1  NaN
2       2  2.0       4  4.0
3       3  3.0       3  3.0
```

I want:

```
          PartieA      PARTIEB     
          col2    col1 col2
    col1  NaN       0  NaN
       0  NaN       1  NaN
       1  2.0       4  4.0
       2  3.0       3  3.0
```

Comment: what should be the expected output? After concat you will have a MultiIndex with 2 col1 columns (as second level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select `MultiIndex` by tuple and then rename index name by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
result = result.set_index([('PartieA','col1')]).rename_axis('col1')
print(result)

     PartieA PARTIEB     
        col2    col1 col2
col1                     
0        NaN       0  NaN
1        NaN       1  NaN
2        2.0       4  4.0
3        3.0       3  3.0
```

Because index is same like original, aslo is possible remove column by tuple:

```
result = result.drop([('PartieA','col1')], axis=1).rename_axis('col1')
print(result)
     PartieA PARTIEB     
        col2    col1 col2
col1                     
0        NaN       0  NaN
1        NaN       1  NaN
2        2.0       4  4.0
3        3.0       3  3.0
```

Comment: but why PARTIEB and not PartieA? OK OP edited after your answer, that was damn luck :D

Comment: @mozway - for see difference in both levels